# How to graph $r=3\times \sin(2\times \phi)\times \sin(2\times \theta)-1$?

Tags: graphing-functions

> $r=3 \sin(2 \phi) \sin(2\theta)-1$

How to graph this function: Preferably on Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: tried and failed: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=r%3D3*sin(2*phi)*sin(2*theta)-1

Comment: It is a function $f:\mathbb{R^3} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ therefore you cannot have its image drawn in a 3-dimensional plot. You can have a look at its surface levels. On the other hand, if you're trying to plot $f(\varphi,\theta) = 3sin(2\varphi)sin(2\theta) - 1$, try just to write the right hand side of the equation.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli oh whoops. I didn't even notice. My bad.